# efficient way other than the if else statement to process a lot of data [Duplicated]

Tags: python

i need to compare a lot of data, what i'm doing right now is using if else statement but it will cost thousands of line, is there any efficient way to do it properly ?. this is the code :

```
// the data will look like this
selected_data_jan = [20]
year1_jan = [30]
// the data is a sum from several lists

if selected_data_jan[0] < year1_jan[0] :
    result = selected_data_jan[0] - year1_jan[0]
    condition_decrease.append("value decrease this year" +result+ " cases")
elif selected_data_jan[0] > year1_jan[0] :
    result = selected_data_jan[0] - year1_jan[0]
    condition_increase.append("value increase this year" +result+ " cases")
    if selected_data_jan[0] > year1_jan[0] *2:
        result = selected_data_jan[0] - year1_jan[0]*2
        condition_increase.clear()
        condition_increase.append("value increased 2-fold this year, as much" +result+ "cases")
else:
    result = selected_data_jan[0] - year1_jan[0]
    condition_equal.append("value equal this year")

//after this selected_data_jan will be compared with year2 and year3
//and there will be selected_data_feb,mar,apr...des too
```

the `selected_data_jan` (monthly) and `year1_jan` (yearly) got the value form dataframe and turn it into a list, and the list value will be like this :

```
selected_data_jan_raw = [6,3,5,6]
// then ill sum the list
selected_data_jan = sum(selected_data_jan_raw)
```

i want to do it efficiently and fewer lines, if I did it the way I do it now it would take thousands of lines, how can i make it work the way i want ?. thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @deadshot i want to do it efficiently and few lines, if I did it the way I do it now it would take thousands of lines

Comment: are these lists? `selected_data_jan` and `year1_jan`. are you sure you are comparing them correctly?

Comment: can't you create a list for `selected_data` with 12 values (one for each year) and `year` as a dictionary where the key is the year and values are the 12 values from `selected_data`. That way you can iterate thru the dictionary and search for months one by one.

Comment: aw sorry, my bad, i forgot to write the index, ill edit it

Comment: also, `result` is a number. don't you need to convert to string while trying to append the data?

Comment: can you share more details about how data is stored in `selected_data_jan` and `year1_jan` or `year2_jan`.  Will `selected_data_jan` have year1, 2, 3, etc?

Comment: @JoeFerndz I also thought the same thing but how do I append monthly calculations on a different list ? each month has a different `condition` list

Comment: @JoeFerndz oke, ill edit it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create something like this to repeat the process. I am not sure how your data is. I am making assumptions. Once I know what your data will look like, the solution can be tweaked.

```
def check_result(sel_mon, year):
    if sel_mon < year:
        diff = sel_mon - year
        cond = 'de'
        results = "value decrease this year" + str(diff)+ " cases"
    elif sel_mon > (year * 2):
        cond = 'i2'
        diff = sel_mon - (year * 2)
        results = "value increase 2-fold this year, as much" +str(diff)+ " cases"
    elif sel_mon > year:
        cond = 'i1'
        diff = sel_mon - year
        results = "value increase this year" +str(diff)+ " cases"
    else:
        cond = 'eq'
        diff = sel_mon - year
        results = "value equal this year"

    return cond, results


selected_data = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120]
years = [40,50,60,80]

for yrs in years:
    for mon in selected_data:
        condition, cond_result = check_result(mon,yrs)

        #for each year, you can send the selected data
        #assumption is selected data is constant for various years
        
        #now you have the type of result
        #de = decreased, i1 = increased, i2 = 2-fold increase, eq = equal
        #you also have the result string to work with
```

Comment: yeah i got it now, this will do. I just need to read the index in the list for specific results. thanks so much @Joe Ferndz